# Вопрос на собеседовании: С# + MSSQL

Tags: sql

Добрый день!
Помогите разобраться - готовлюсь к собеседованию, в инете нашел вопрос:
Все ли верно в данном запросе?

```
Select * 
from clients as cl where client_tel = null
Left join contract as co on co.contr_id = cl.contr_id
Where co.money > 20000 and cl.region = ‘Москва’
```

Спасибо.
Вроде как выбираем клиентов без телефона из Москвы с договором от 20к. Похоже верно, я думаю. А как Вы считаете ?

Comment: А причём тут C#? (Да и конкретикой mssql тут вроде не пахнет.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. синтаксис неверный. where должно идти после всех join'ов, и притом одно.
2. left join превратится в inner join, т.к. присутствуют условия по таблице contract во where
3. select * - писать плохо. нет котороля над тем, что выбирается, плюс совпадающие имена полей в соединяемых таблицах в зависимости от субд могут выбираться по-разному, вплоть до ошибки в запросе.

Перепишите запрос корректно, потом уже будет видно то ли вы вибираете.

Answer (score 3):

```
Select * 
from clients as cl
Left join contract as co on co.contr_id = cl.contr_id
Where co.money > 20000 and cl.region = ‘Москва’ AND cl.client_tel = null
```

Comment: Я бы последние условие вот так бы на писал:
... AND (cl.client_tel = null OR AND cl.client_tel = '')